# Can we travel to/return from a Schengen country with a different air carriers

Tags: europe, airlines

We have booked a return ticket from Vienna to Delhi. The entry ticket is from Jet Airlines from Delhi to Paris.

Would it be problematic if we fly from Delhi to Nice or Paris via Jet Airlines, and return to Delhi from Vienna via Air India? The PNR is different in this case, and the ticket will not be on one page.

We applied for a Schengen visa from France; will it be mandatory to spend the maximum time of stay in France?

Comment: Please ask one question at once. For now you have two completely different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applying for a Schengen visa, you should apply from the country you plan to spend the most time in. If the majority of your visit will be in France, it is appropriate to apply for a visa from the French consulate. However, if the majority of your visit will actually be in Austria, you should apply to the Austrian consulate and not the French.

There is no problem with having two separate tickets for your inbound and outbound flights, as long as they accurately demonstrate your entering and existing the Schengen zone. Simply include both of your tickets and their information in your application.